# Does the Mann-Whitney U-test require the groups to have the same distribution?

Tags: assumptions, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

If one of my data sets is normally distributed and the other is not, can I do a Mann-Whitney U-test on them, or would they both have to be non-normal?

Comment: It may be okay. What are the null and alternative you're actually interested in testing? (don't look up how your book says to word it for M-W -- what are you trying to find out in plain words?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Mann-Whitney $U$-test, the distributions can be arbitrary (any old thing--they do not have to be normal).  However, the test does assume that the distributions would be identical under the null (e.g., both chi-squared with the same parameters).  If you believe the distributions are not the same and certainly would not be, even if the null hypothesis were true, then it is not clear why you are testing if the distributions differ or what exactly you are trying to test.  Tests can still be conducted to scrutinize less common aspects of the distributions (making something up: to see if two different types of distributions, but with the same mean, differ in variance), but it would require some hard thinking to determine what such a difference would mean and how to validly test it.

Comment: whats the most accurate method of testing for normality in a large group (270 sample size)

Comment: @ZoeCampbell, as I mentioned in my answer to your other question, testing for normality is probably not necessary w/ your sample size & not a good thing to do anyway. You should read the thread I linked in that answer.

Comment: so what test should I use then for to see if there is a significant difference between the means? sorry to ask so much, have absolutely no idea about stats and now have to use them!

Comment: @ZoeCampbell, as I mentioned in my answer to your other question, based on your description of your situation, I suspect you are safe to use a t-test b/c you have a lot of data & both histograms look normal.

Comment: ok ill use the t test so, its just that its for a thesis and we were told it was important to perform tests according to whether the data is parametric or not. I have 9 data sets but only need to compare sets of 2, all look to be normally distributed on the histograms, but some are SLightly to the left or right , still with a bell shaped curve! i pressed thumb up on your comment

Comment: @ZoeCampbell, please try reading the thread I linked in your other question. If you have a lot of data, any trivial difference will make the test of normality significant, even if your data are fine for the t-test.

Comment: Actually, as the Mann-Whitney formulation of the problem in terms of U-statistics makes clear, even under the null you don't have to assume the same shape, only that there's no stochastic dominance (specifically, under the null, $P(X<Y)=\frac{_1}{^2}$ is all that's needed). In many situations, it makes sense to restrict ourselves to equality under the null (it includes the useful location-shift and scale-shift alternatives, for example), but it's not needed for the test to have the correct null distribution. Conover's book is an example of one with the explicit general formulation of the null.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Glen_b. The wikipedia page states that an assumption of MW is "the distributions of both groups are equal under the null hypothesis" (#3). It must be wrong.

Comment: Actually, the Mann-Whitney entry in Wikipedia isn't quite wrong, but is slightly misleading. Note that item 3 is under "*a* very general formulation" - indeed just above that, it says "*there are many other ways to formulate the null and alternative hypotheses such that the MWW test will give a valid test*". Even within item 3, the part after "so that" correctly describes the null that "4" is actually the alternative of. It's [correct at this date](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test&oldid=380569387), but is subsequently (& unnecessarily) changed.